# EE6 Error Messages After Install

Tags: php-errors

Just tried installing EE6 on two different servers (one installation on MediaTemple, one on BlueHost) and in each case I am seeing error messages when trying to save URL and Path settings. Additionally I am seeing error messages on the front end home page. Both servers have been tested with ee_wizard and are 100% compatible - I have extensive experience running EE on both hosting services for years. These are fresh installations of EE 6.0 - the errors are appearing immediately after running installation via admin.php.

```
Errors I am seeing after trying to save URL and Path Settings page in backend:

Warning
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
ee/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Settings/Settings.php, line 209
Severity: E_WARNING

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:124)
ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 265
Severity: E_WARNING

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:124)
ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php, line 500
Severity: E_WARNING
```

```
Errors I am seeing on home page (with debugging enabled):

Notice
Only variables should be passed by reference
ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php, line 2256
Severity: E_NOTICE

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:124)
ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.common.php, line 495
Severity: E_WARNING
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I had some errors after upgrading too. I had to go back and make sure everything was set properly in the config.php instead of updating them from the CP however. Have you tried that?